# How to create maven project with two clicks in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e

How to create maven project with two clicks in Eclipse?
(One click to open Dialog, then enter names etc, click finish).

in other words

Is there way to configure icon or shortcut to New Maven Project dialog?
(And not go through 5 clicks File -> New -> Project -> Maven -> Maven Project)

I need the most simple way to create maven project that beginners can remember.

[image: New Maven Project dialog]

Comment: You need at least two supplemtal clicks once on "Next" and afterwards on "Finish".

Comment: you would need at least a projectname. so 1 ckick will be difficult. I thing you need to write a custom eclipse plugin for that. But that should not be rocket science.

Comment: OK, let it be 2 clicks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Press Ctrl+3 (In Eclipse Juno 3.8 or 4.2)
2. type maven select New Maven Project
   [image: Ctrl3]

See also
http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseShortcuts/article.html